# graphicsmagick draw rectangle - converting from imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert all my Imagemagick code over to GraphicsMagick to help speed up the process since we do about 5 a second. Just about everything worked just by changing out convert command to gm convert. But can't figure out why this one will not draw the rectangle.

```
gm convert /MYIMAGE.jpg \ -fill '#0007' -draw 'rectangle 0,342,508,392' \ -gravity North -pointsize \ 18 -fill white -annotate +0+350 'My Image Text Here' \ /MYIMAGE.jpg
```

I have been playing with it for hours and bee on their site all morning. Can't really see what the issue is. Like I said, every single of my other actions work perfect in GM. So not a issue with GM running, just something different from ImageMagick that im not seeing. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Change the comma after 342 to a space. I am intrigued by your statement IM is too slow - I can process 84 images per sec as above at 1024x768 on a desktop Mac. What size are your images please? What OS? And do you do the same processing on all images?

Comment: I figured it out actually. It was the -annotate that was getting in the way. Graphicsmagicks uses -draw 'text. As far as speed goes, the issues I see with Imagemagick speed is the resize mostly (highres). We do allot of image processing, millions a day so all it takes is a few processes to get stuck for a second and it seems to built up fast. Graphicksmagick does seem to fix all my speed issues. 

My working command:
gm convert /MYIMAGE.jpg \ -fill '#0007' -draw 'rectangle 0,259.5,523,309.5' \ -gravity North -pointsize \ 18 -fill white -draw 'text +0+277.5 "My Text"' \ /MYIMAGE.jpg

Comment: Would you care to answer my questions please so I can try and improve your speed?

Comment: Our images vary is size as they are user uploaded. Lately most seem to be high res, and we now accept photos directly from users phone camera and most are 12 mega pixel or so. OS is CentOS 6.7. The image processing changes based on what the user selects, it can rotate, crop, distort, etc.. GM fixed our speed issues 100%. For more info on why you can just checkout their page http://www.graphicsmagick.org/index.html or  test yourself using their benchmark script http://www.graphicsmagick.org/benchmarks.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/api/draw.html#drawrectangle

Also changing your Imagemagick install from a 16bit one to a 8bit may improve speed as I belive that is one reason graphicsmagick is faster.

EDIT:
You need to specify all the relavent information when you ask a question.

Anyway why do you have all the backslashes in your code?

Comment: I am using command line not API. So the docs are 
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw

I am doing them correct, they are also suppose to be same as ImageMagick, that's where the confusion comes.

Comment: To compare http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-draw should be the same. But it doesn't work on any of my servers. So not sure if its a known issue or if anyone has experienced this.